# Nexus can not access configured Proxy Repositories such as Maven Central

Tags: maven, nexus

our company has a Maven Repository (Nexus Version 1.4.0 Open Source), this repository hosts company artifacts and also it configured with some proxy repositories (like Maven Central). now the problem is that Nexus can not access to some of the repositories including Maven Central. this is really frustrating.

in Nexus web interface the status of these broken repositories is : "In Service - Attempting to Proxy and Remote Unavailable".

I have no idea what to do.

Comment: Which version do you use? 1.4. ? I don't believe?

Comment: yes it is 1.4!, I have just joined a company and this is the version installed

Comment: You should really upgrade to at least 2.14.x

Comment: Really Oh my lord. ..upgrade to at least to 2.X or even better to 3.X this otherwise you will get in more troubles...

Comment: yes I agree, this should be our priority. but for at least one week I have to work with this version, because there are some deadlines and I have no time for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really an answer but a couple thoughts that can lead to the solution:

1. Since January 2020 maven central moved to https - maybe you should configure nexus accordingly (see [this blog post from sonatype](https://blog.sonatype.com/central-repository-moving-to-https))
2. There might be a network configuration (firewall or whatever) that restricts nexus to make a connection to the mvn central. Maybe its worth to consult with network / admin people.
3. Nexus itself must have logs - maybe you'll find some information there.

Comment: I checked, all broken repositories URL starts with `HTTP`, I changed this to `HTTPS`, nothing happened.

Comment: is there any special configuration in Nexus for using `HTTPS` repos? or I just need to configure the server operating system (firewalls and ...)?